# React Native - Display the image or Document file from S3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, react-native, amazon-s3, hybrid-mobile-app

I am building both the Webapp(Angular) and Hybrid app(React native) for a product. Previous, there is no restriction or bucket policy for the S3 storage. So, I can access the file directly using the s3 link.
ex: bucket-name.s3.region.amazonaws.com/PUwXksSAsQVCW1k73M0IgazjVckt3Ey4wwDkHga9.jpeg

Now, I have updated the bucket policy and added the webapp domain name in the referer. Its working fine for Webapp. I want the same in hybrid app too but I doesn't have a idea to fix the 403 issue. React native app is not loading/displaying the s3 image, it return 'access denied' error message.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "http referer policy example",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "http://localhost:4200/*",
                    "http://localhost:8000/*",
                    "http://localhost:8081/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Could any one help on this. Thanks in Advance.